# React doesn't change to LoggedInView when Meteor user logs in

Tags: reactjs, authentication, meteor, state

I am developing a React + Meteor application and I'm having trouble with the user login functionality.

I have a header navbar that displays a different component based on whether or not the user is logged in.

Like this:

```
export default class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            user: Meteor.user()
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <header className="main-header">
                <nav className="navbar navbar-static-top">
                    <div className="navbar-custom-menu">
                        {this.state.user() !== null ? <LoggedInNavigation /> : <LoggedOutNavigation />}
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        )
    }
}
```

Now this works but it doesn't change upon a user being logged in.  I have to refresh the page in order to change the views (which obviously is not ideal).

Here is my login code:

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password, (error) => {
    if (error)
        this.setState({ meteorError: "Error: " + error.reason })
    else {
        this.setState({ meteorError: "" })
        // Handle successful login
    }
})
```

The problem is these two blocks of code sit in different components.

The first block is in `imports/ui/components/main-layout/Header` and the second block is in `imports/ui/components/authentication/Login`.

As I said, the problem is that the user can log in but the view doesn't change according to the authentication state. What's the best practice to solving this?

**EDIT:**

Here is the hierarchy of components:

1 - LoggedOutNav

```
MainLayout -> Header -> LoggedOutNav
```

2 - Login Code

```
MainLayout -> Routes -> (Route path="/login" component={Login}) -> LoginForm
```

Comment: That won't work because the state has to change in order if it to re-render...

Comment: The view won't change because render **will be called again only if this.setState** (and you aren't calling setState in the Header when the login is successful) is used or the props provided to the Component change. In order to find out a good solution to your particular case, you should tell us the relation between these components (parent-child, children of another component...).

Comment: I'll update my question (there's a very distance relation)

Comment: @CésarLandesa done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the constructor of your class will only run once and never again as long as the component is mounted. So even though `Meteor.user()` will change, your `state` won't. The component will rerender when a) the `props` change or b) your `state` changes e.g. when you call `setState`. We can leverage a) through meteors `createContainer` HOC ([react-meteor-data](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data)) to wrap your `Header` class and set a reactive data context for it. When the data changes, the props for `Header` will change and the component rerenders. In code that would be something like:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class HeaderComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        const { user } = this.props;
        return (
            <header className="main-header">
                <nav className="navbar navbar-static-top">
                    <div className="navbar-custom-menu">
                        {user ? <LoggedInNavigation /> : <LoggedOutNavigation />}
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        )
    }
}

export const Header = createContainer(() => {
    // assuming you have a user publication of that name...
    Meteor.subscribe('users/personalData');
    return {
        user: Meteor.user(),
    };
}, HeaderComponent);
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.